# Generating downloadable .csv file with javascript function inline html using <script></script> from javascript variables from multiple clients

Tags: javascript, html, csv, google-sheets

I want to be able to store these variables on the website and generate a .csv file with multiple user's input. Here is my code for a question:

```
<label for="Q4">Q4: </label>
<input type="number" name="Q4" id="Q4">
<button id="Q4Button" onclick="Q4Submit()">Submit</button> <br>

<script>
    function Q4Submit() {
        var Q4 = document.getElementsByName("Q4")[0].value;
        var resQ4 = document.getElementById("Q4").innerHTML;
        var repQ4 = Q4.replace(resQ4, function (x) {
            return x.toUpperCase();
        });
        document.getElementById("Q4").innerHTML = repQ4;
    }
</script>
```

The Q4 being short for Question 4. I have 45 questions.
This will get the user's input from a text box when they hit the submit button associated with that text box, and it will store it into a variable, as well as inside the user's local html code. It works somehow just the way I want it to. I just need help with grouping users together. This is for a school-wide test in which we need students to put their name and year. I want the website to group the names by their inputted year, so I can generate a massive .csv file with all of the student's responses from that year to be stored on the server. This file will be generated and downloaded on demand by a teacher by pressing a button and typing a password.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a basic survey form. You may want to create a [Google Form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) to store the responses in a spreadsheet, instead of writing your own code to do the same. Form responses are easy to download as .csv. You can limit access through Google Docs Editors sharing features.

Comment: I need to have each student's response in the same .csv so I can't just use Google Forms to store their responses... I'm using JavaScript now to just have it generate a .csv with the responses from the website through variables. It works!! Although I still can't make them all merge into one .csv

Comment: Form responses automatically appear on a separate tab in a response destination spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion and can all be downloaded as one .csv file through **File > Download > Comma-separated values** in the spreadsheet, or directly through the form editor. You may have invested a lot of time in your current solution, but I would recommend that you also consider tried and tested solutions that deliver the functionality right out of the box. See [bygones principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost#Bygones_principle).